# Use comma as separator to separate input as chips in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to separate my input value by comma, and when I hit enter, the each value before comma has its own chip.

Here is what is looks like before enter[before enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erIiv.png)

and here is what should looks like after enter:[after enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkzOg.png)

the code look like this now, I can't seem make the comma separator work.

```
new Vue({
  el:'div',
  props: {
    set: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chips:[],
      currentInput: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveChip() {
      const {chips, currentInput, set} = this;
      ((set && chips.indexOf(currentInput) === -1) || !set) && chips.push(currentInput);
      this.currentInput = '';
    },
    deleteChip(index) {
      this.chips.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="chip-container">
      <div class="chip" v-for="(chip, i) of chips" :key="chip.label">
<span v-for="chip in chips.split(',')" v-text="chip"></span>

        <i class="material-icons" @click="deleteChip(i)">clear</i>
      </div>
      <input v-model="currentInput" @keypress.enter="saveChip" >
    </div>
  `
})
```

Here is codepen:https://codepen.io/lydchair/pen/PoNEJjb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell if your raw data contains a space after the comma, (I guess no). If not, this might be the reason. You seperate by ', '.

Edit:

This code is running for me, as an chips.vue file. I added some style border below to visualize the single span-Elements which are generated.

```
<template>
  <div class="chip-container">
    <div class="chip" v-for="(chip, i) of chips" :key="chip.label">
      <span v-for="oneChip in chip.split(',')" v-text="oneChip"></span>
      <i class="material-icons" @click="deleteChip(i)">clear</i>
    </div>
    <input v-model="currentInput" @keypress.enter="saveChip" >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: { 
    set: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chips:[],
      currentInput: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveChip() {
      const {chips, currentInput, set} = this;
      ((set && chips.indexOf(currentInput) === -1) || !set) && chips.push(currentInput);
      this.currentInput = '';
    },
    deleteChip(index) {
      this.chips.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  span {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
```

I filled the input below with:
abc
abc,def,geh

both created a new row (with trailing clear) and abc,def,geh have a red border each.

Comment: that's was good catch! but the problem is still there, I'm not able to get value after hit enter

Comment: Is your for-Loop correct then? your div-for is looping over the chips not splitted, while the inner span loops again but splitted... Seems odd to me.

Comment: Yep. If I change the line to `<span v-for="chip in chip.split(',')" v-text="chip"></span>` it seems to work fine. There is even a console.error entry before, telling you to not call split on an array :)

Comment: You mean you have changed <span v-for="chip in chips.split(',')" v-text="chip"></span> to <span v-for="chip in chip.split(',')" v-text="chip"></span> ?t it's still not working, I only got one value after comma